Hasura log shows UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE is being used when actual x-hasura-role has no table permissions
I was configuring nextJS to query Hasura, passing a JWT as a header in each request.
I used an ApolloProvider along with ApolloClient and ApolloLink like this:
headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${session.signedJwt}`;
headers['x-hasura-role'] = 'user';
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri, headers });
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link:  httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true,
});
return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>

which is a pretty standard provider pattern.
I also set up the server to use JWT authentication, which included adding the following environment variables (amoungst others) to my docker-compose.yaml file:
HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: SuperUltraSecret
HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{ "type": "HS256", "key": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef" }'
HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE: serverless_function

I have a hasura table named "Sites". I have a user role named user in hasura.
When the sites  table grants NO permission to the user user role:

the hasura logs for this request says:
{"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"172.18.0.1","method":"POST","status":200,"url":"/v1/graphql"},"operation":{"error":{"code":"validation-failed","error":"field 'sites' not found in type: 'query_root'","path":"$.selectionSet.sites"},"query":{"operationName":"Sites","query":"query Sites {\n  sites {\n    name\n    uuid\n    __typename\n  }\n}","variables":{}},"query_execution_time":1.88333e-4,"request_id":"4ad40873-537e-44ad-abae-5392bcb7ff4e","request_mode":"error","request_read_time":2.125e-6,"response_size":114,"uncompressed_response_size":114,"user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"serverless_function"}},"request_id":"4ad40873-537e-44ad-abae-5392bcb7ff4e"},"level":"error","span_id":"a8e20cfbd5361b03","timestamp":"2024-12-30T19:26:36.669+0000","trace_id":"1fb2ce66b18238aab505a9962ef1276d","type":"http-log"}
Which indicates an error - which is correct because the user userrole can not see this table.
However, what threw me was the "user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"serverless_function"}} part of this error log.
I spent hours diagnosing why the query was processing as the unauthorised role!
However, when I granted select access to the user user role and ran the same query, this log changes to what I expected:
{"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"172.18.0.1","method":"POST","status":200,"url":"/v1/graphql"},"operation":{"error":{"code":"validation-failed","error":"field 'name' not found in type: 'sites'","path":"$.selectionSet.sites.selectionSet.name"},"query":{"operationName":"Sites","query":"query Sites {\n  sites {\n    name\n    uuid\n    __typename\n  }\n}","variables":{}},"query_execution_time":8.90125e-4,"request_id":"942b4c84-6c09-4af0-9e8e-2744ad7756d5","request_mode":"error","request_read_time":4.583e-6,"response_size":126,"uncompressed_response_size":126,"user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"user","x-hasura-user-id":"d377181c-14f2-40e3-a1bb-1bb7bbdf49d5"}},"request_id":"942b4c84-6c09-4af0-9e8e-2744ad7756d5"},"level":"error","span_id":"c26213b8ada03443","timestamp":"2024-12-31T00:40:55.686+0000","trace_id":"8e24f19b7aa24ef4d6fb5b72a0646a25","type":"http-log"}
As I did not provide access for the user user role to any fields in the table, I expect to get an error when I query those fields.
However, the role is now correctly included in user_vars: "user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"user","x-hasura-user-id":"d377181c-14f2-40e3-a1bb-1bb7bbdf49d5"}}
So I blew several too many hours diagnosing why the server was not correctly extracting my user role from the JWT token - when it actually was.
Do you think this is a bug or a feature? Should I report to Hasura, or do you think this is how it "should" work.
